# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter not show media info in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, media-player, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I tried this code to show media info in Lockscreen and Control center but it does not show anything:

```
Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");

if (playingInfoCenter) {


    NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imagedNamed:@"AlbumArt"]];

    [songInfo setObject:@"Audio Title" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    [songInfo setObject:@"Audio Author" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    [songInfo setObject:@"Audio Album" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    [songInfo setObject:albumArt forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];

}
```

I also set `FirstResponding` but still not see anything.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"is first resp: %i",[self isFirstResponder]);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    // Initialize the AVAudioSession here.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

How can i fix that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you activated "Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture" as shown below?

[image]